# Compare this two columns with different format in hive

Tags: if-statement, hive, case, string-comparison

I have source table: b_ACCOUNT.b_curreny and target table account.currency. 
The source table b_ACCOUNT.b_curreny currency format is 'c' and 'U' and the target table account.currency format is ‘CAD’ and ‘USD’

I use case to change 'c' and 'U' format to 'CAD' and 'USD' and compare this two columns. I use the following query and this query is still compared target column acc.CURRENCY (CAD) with the source column b.b_curreny(c)'

SELECT count(*) count ,

case 
WHEN b_curreny ='C' THEN 'CAD'

WHEN b_curreny ='U' THEN 'USD'

ELSE NULL END

FROM ACCOUNT acc

join b_ACCOUNT b on acc.account_NUMBER=b.account_NUMBER

and acc.CURRENCY <> b.b_curreny

If I use the following query, I get error message Invalid table alias or column reference 'souce_currency':

SELECT count(*) count ,

case 
WHEN b_curreny ='C' THEN 'CAD'

WHEN b_curreny ='U' THEN 'USD'

ELSE NULL END assource_curreny

FROM ACCOUNT acc

join b_ACCOUNT b on acc.account_NUMBER=b.account_NUMBER

and acc.CURRENCY <> source_curreny

Could you help me to compare these two columns with a different format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column - ***source_curreny*** is created in the select clause of query and being used in the same query. Hence, this error. You may use a outer query to refer to this alias.

If you are interested in the mismatch count, you may try the below query. (I haven't tested it)

```
SELECT sum (case WHEN b.b_curreny ='C' and acc.CURRENCY!='CAD' THEN 1 
             WHEN b_curreny ='U' and  acc.CURRENCY!='USD' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0
            END) as mismatch_count
FROM ACCOUNT acc
join b_ACCOUNT b  
on acc.account_NUMBER=b.account_NUMBER;
```

Comment: Please note that - you may need to handle null case as well.